# Trying to run a client from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I'm trying to run a minecraft client from eclipse to easily go about accessing and testing mods while I'm developing them. I've done a lot of research trying to figure out this error but for some reason no matter how I configure my run environment it will always give this error:

```
[2021-03-29 22:15:18] [INFO   ] Natives: C:\Users\daniel\Documents\Minecraft Modding\projects\Gemstones_\build\natives 
[2021-03-29 22:15:18] [INFO   ] Main Class: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch 
[2021-03-29 22:15:18] [INFO   ] Srg2Mcp: C:\Users\daniel\Documents\Minecraft Modding\projects\Gemstones_\build\createSrgToMcp\output.srg 
[2021-03-29 22:15:18] [INFO   ] Extra: [] 
[2021-03-29 22:15:18] [INFO   ] Running with arguments: [--version, 1.12, --assetIndex, 1.12, --assetsDir, C:\Users\daniel\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --accessToken, {REDACTED}, --userProperties, [], --tweakClass, net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker] 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: What version of Java, and what version of Minecraft?

Comment: Looks like you are running a recent version of Java and Minecraft is doing something that no longer works. You probably need to run with Java 8 - the last version where this operation worked. So you need to change the 'Run Configuration' in Eclipse to use Java 8

Comment: Its Minecraft 1.12.2, forge version 14.23.5.54. My version on java shouldn't be an issue, I'm running Java 1.8u281 for both the JDK and the runtime environment

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it out, the java version eclipse was using wasn't supported, but I had the correct one installed. By default eclipse was using their java jre 1.8, so to fix this I went to "Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs" then clicked "Add... > Standard VM", then entered the path of my JDK (C:\Program Files\Java*jdk_VERSION*), then applied and went to the Execution Environment and selected my new jdk path there. I only forgot this step; to go change the run configuration environment on the runClient to the new JDK I added.

Thank you for your help!